# How to print if the year is leap using if else statements

Tags: python, if-statement

```py
inp = input("Enter the year: ")
res = "This is not a leap year!"
```

This code stays the same

```py
print(res)
```

Comment: Forget Python for a moment.  Do you know how to decide if a year is a leap year just using pen and paper?

Answer (score 0):

All leap years are divisible by 4 but not divisible by 100 except if they are divisible by 400. So we can just check if the year is divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100 or divisible by 400 using [`%` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp). Here is the code:

```
inp = input("Enter the year: ")
if int(inp) % 4 == 0 and int(inp) % 100 != 0 or int(inp) % 400 == 0:
    print("This is a leap year!")
else:
    print("This is not a leap year!")
```

Or, if you need to use `res` you can just do `print(res)` instead of `print("This is not a leap year!")`

Comment: This isn't correct! Leap years are divisible by 4 but not if they are divisible by 100 except if they are divisible by 400. I.e. 1900 was a not a leap year but 2000 was. This nested if-else is probably the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if int(inp)%400==0:
    print("this is a leap year")
elif int(inp)%100=0: 
    print(res)
elif int(inp)%4==0:
    print("this is a leap year")
else:
    print(res)
```